# Sqlite gives conflict avg for a column of comma-separated numbers

Tags: types, sqlite

My sql statement in Sqlite gets the following:

`sqlite> select avg(turnover),min(turnover) from stock_history where turnover > 10000;
avg(turnover)     min(turnover)

---

277.854759767152  1,000,048,325`

The data in column turnover are all comma-separated numbers.
I'd like to have some error messages instead of above non-logic results - numbers bigger than 10000 numbers gets average just 277.854....

Is it possible to have integrity rule on the data, or configuration to interpret comma as thousand separator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the commas, you can use [replace()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace):

```
UPDATE Stock_History
SET turnover = CAST(replace(turnover, ',', '') AS NUMBER);
```

To prevent non-numeric values, add a CHECK constraint to the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Stock_History (
    [...],
    turnover NUMBER  CHECK(typeof(turnover) IN ('integer', 'real')),
    [...]
);
```

Comment: I just got the description in SQLite document: <br>
`... Included in the definition of "column constraints" for the purposes of the previous statement are the COLLATE and DEFAULT clauses, even though these are not really constraints in the sense that they do not restrict the data that the table may contain.`
 It seems to most persons the type right after column name should work as a CHECK, but it is not.